# Warning "Using uninitialized memory 'x' " when trying to work with an element from an array even though I read all the elements

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, array-merge

I'm trying to combine two sorted arrays and when I compare two of the elements, each one from one of the two arrays, I get the warning " Using uninitialized memory 'x' ".

Here is my input:

```
5 
1 3 5 7 9 
5 
2 4 6 8 10
```

And the output:

```
-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n, m;
    int a[100], b[100], c[201];
    std::cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cin >> a[i];
    } 
    std::cin >> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        std::cin >> b[i];
    } 
    int i = 0; int j = 0; int k = 0;
    while (i <= n && j <= m) {
        if (a[i] > b[j]) {
            c[k] = a[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {
            c[k] = b[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i < n) {
        for (int p = k; p < n; p++) {
            c[p] = a[i];
        }
    }
    while (j < m) {
        for (int p = k; p < m; p++) {
            c[p] = b[j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        std::cout << c[k];
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (i <= n && j <= m)` is not correct -- you will read 1 past the end of what you input (array index starts at 0, the last valid input was index `n-1`)

Comment: It's a bit strange that your question's title is more descriptive than the question's body. You might want to review [ask].

Comment: *"'Using uninitialized memory' [...] even though I read all the elements"* -- The "even though" phrasing suggests a contradiction, but this is more of a confirmation. The warning is because you are reading more than you wrote. For a contradiction, you should assert that you **wrote** all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

The condition of the while loop

```
while (i <= n && j <= m) {
    if (a[i] > b[j]) {
        c[k] = a[i];
        i++;
    }
    else {
        c[k] = b[j];
        j++;
    }
    k++;
}
```

is invalid. If for example the array `a` has `n` initialized elements then the valid index for the array is in the range `[0, n)`.  Using the expression `a[n]` results either in accessing memory outside the array `a` or in reading an uninitialized element of the array.

So you need to write

```
while (i < n && j < m) {
    if (a[i] > b[j]) {
        c[k] = a[i];
        i++;
    }
    else {
        c[k] = b[j];
        j++;
    }
    k++;
}
```

Also bear in mind that usually only when an element of the second container (array) is greater than a corresponding element of the first container (array) then it is written in the result container.

That is the if statement should look like

```
    if ( a[i] < b[j] ) {
        c[k] = b[j];
        j++;
    }
    else {
        c[k] = a[i];
        i++;
    }
```

if you want to  merge arrays in the descending order.

Or

```
    if ( b[j] < a[i] ) {
        c[k] = b[j];
        j++;
    }
    else {
        c[k] = a[i];
        i++;
    }
```

if you want to merge arrays in the ascending order. And you are going to merge your arrays in the ascending order.

These while loops

```
while (i < n) {
    for (int p = k; p < n; p++) {
        c[p] = a[i];
    }
}
while (j < m) {
    for (int p = k; p < m; p++) {
        c[p] = b[j];
    }
}
```

can be infinite loops because neither the variable `i` nor the variable `j` are being changed within the loops. At least they try to assign the same elements `a[i]` and `b[j]` to elements of the array `c`. And moreover the value of the variable `k` can be greater than the value of the variable `n` and greater than the value of the variable `m` though either array `a` or the array `b` has elements that were not yet copied in the array `c`.

Instead you should write

```
while (i < n) c[k++] = a[i++];
while (j < m) c[k++] = b[j++];
```

Pay attention to that you should check that entered values of the variables `n` and `m` are not greater than `100`.

And there is no great sense to declare the array `c` with `201` elements instead of `200` elements

```
int a[100], b[100], c[201];
```

Pay attention that there is standard algorithm `std::merge` declared in header `<algorithm>` that you could use. Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
    int b[] = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };
    int c[std::size( a ) + std::size( b )];

    std::merge( a, a + std::size( a ), b, b + std::size( b ), c );

    for (const auto item : c)
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

In the program there are not used standard functions `std;:begin` and std::end becuase in your program you are using sub-arrays. Though you could write in your program for example

```
    std::merge( std::begin( a ), std::next( std::begin( a ), n ),
                std::begin( b ), std::next( std::begin( b ), m ),  
                std::begin( c ) );
```

Instead of the arrays with predefined sizes you could use standard container `std::vector<int>` that allows to specify an arbitrary number of elements. With objects of the container you can use the same subscript operator.

Comment: *"That is the if statement should look like"* - No, that's actually *worse*. Both theirs and yours are wrong and don't work, but theirs at least already has the correct comparison for stable sorting.

Comment: @KellyBundy You should investigate how the standard algorithm std::merge is implemented. After that you will not write your senseless comments.

Comment: How is pointing out bugs senseless? That's a rather rude comment.

Comment: @KellyBundy Where do you have found a bug?

Comment: Where I told you: under your *"That is the if statement should look like"*. That code doesn't work. It appends the **larger** of the two values. It needs to append the **smaller** one.

Comment: @KellyBundy Thanks. I have updated the answer to make it clear. :)

Comment: Better, I guess. Though their two inputs are ascending. Unclear why you're talking about and then showing how to do descending, and only append ascending as an afterthought...

Comment: @KellyBundy I just pointed out how such if statements should look in the both cases.